# MinHeap Extract/heapDown() failure: incorrect order of elements

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Me and a fellow student sit for hours now at a task and don't get the (small?) error out of our program.

The task is to realize a MinHeap with the possibility to update Elements and sort them new in the MinHeap with a heapDown Function. 
Now we bring it all to work but some Elements of our Heap Array aren't in Place and the List after our Extract (of the smallest Element) is not sorted as she should. 
Hopefully you can help us.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MinPQ2 {
    private PQElement Elemente[];
    private int maxsize;
    private int currentsize;

    public MinPQ2(int max) {
        this.maxsize = max;
        this.currentsize = 0;
        Elemente = new PQElement[this.maxsize];
    }

    private void swap(int eins, int zwei) {//tauscht Elemente innerhalb des Arrays
        PQElement tmp = Elemente[eins];
        Elemente[eins] = Elemente[zwei];
        Elemente[zwei] = tmp;
    }

    public PQElement getLeftChild(int position) {
        return Elemente[position * 2 + 1];
    }

    public PQElement getRightChild(int position) {
        return Elemente[position * 2 + 2];
    }
    public PQElement getQuestioner(int position){
        return Elemente[position];
    }
    public PQElement getParent(int position) {
        return Elemente[position / 2 - ((position > 0 && position % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0)];
    }

    private void heapUp(int position) {
        while (getParent(position).getPriority() > Elemente[position].getPriority()) {
            int temppos = position / 2 - ((position % 2 == 0) ? 1 : 0);
            swap(position, temppos);
            position = temppos;
        }
    }

    private void heapDown(int position) {
        int tmp;
        if (position * 2 + 2 < maxsize && getLeftChild(position) != null){
            if (getRightChild(position) != null){
                if (getLeftChild(position).getPriority() < getRightChild(position).getPriority()){
                    tmp = position *2+1;
                    swap(position,tmp);
                    position = tmp;
                    heapDown(position);
                }
                else {
                    tmp = position *2+2;
                    swap(position,tmp);
                    position = tmp;
                    heapDown(position);
                }
            }
            else if (getLeftChild(position).getPriority() < getQuestioner(position).getPriority()){
                tmp = position *2+1;
                swap(position,tmp);
                position = tmp;
                heapDown(position);
            }
        }
    }


    public boolean insert(PQElement n) {
        if (currentsize >= maxsize)
            return false;
        Elemente[currentsize] = n;
        currentsize++;
        if (currentsize > 1)
            heapUp(currentsize - 1);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean insert(String s, double d) {
        return insert(new PQElement(s, d));
    }

    public PQElement extractElement() {
        if(isEmpty())
            return null;
        PQElement result = Elemente[0];
        swap(0, currentsize-1);
        Elemente[currentsize - 1] = null;
        heapDown(0);
        currentsize--;
        return result;
    }

    public String extractData() {
        return extractElement().getData();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return currentsize == 0;
    }

    public void update(String s, double n) {
        int position = currentsize - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= currentsize; i++) {
            if (i == currentsize)
                return;
            if (Elemente[i].getData().equals(s)) {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        Elemente[position].setPriority(n);
        heapUp(position);
        heapDown(position);
    }
}
```

```
public class PQElement {
    private String data;
    private double Priority;

    public PQElement(String s, double d){
        this.data = s;
        this.Priority = d;
    }
    public String getData(){
        return data;
    }
    public double getPriority(){
        return Priority;
    }
    public void setPriority(double d){
        Priority = d;
    }
    public void setData(String s){
        data = s;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class testclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random zufall = new Random();
        int max = 11;
        MinPQ2 test = new MinPQ2(max);
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            test.insert(i + " Element", zufall.nextDouble());
        }
        System.out.println(test(test, max));
        System.out.println("_____________");
        //test2(test,max);
        System.out.println("_____________");
        test3(test,max,zufall);
    }

    private static boolean test(MinPQ2 test, int max) {
        for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
            if (test.getParent(i).getPriority() < test.getQuestioner(i).getPriority()) {
                System.out.println(test.getParent(i).getPriority() + " : " + test.getQuestioner(i).getPriority());
            } else return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private static void test2(MinPQ2 test, int max) {
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            System.out.println(test.extractElement().getPriority());
        }
    }
    private static void test3(MinPQ2 test, int max, Random zufall){
        for (int i = 1; i < max;i++){
            if (i%2 == 0){
                test.update(i + " Element", zufall.nextDouble());
            }
        }
        test2(test,max);
    }
}
```

This is our Code. 
With `test()` in the testclass(third codesnippet) we just show the Heap and at this spot all works fine.
But now in `test3()` we update some data, reorder them with `heapDown()` (first code snippet) and print them on the screen. Now we see that the extract data isn't in sort. So the mistake might be in `heapDown()` or `update()`. But we try so much, and don't find the solution :(

Comment: You can simplify your `getParent()` to `return (position-1)/2`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your `heapDown` method. I've added comments.

```
private void heapDown(int position) {
    int tmp;
    // You need to check against `currentsize`, rather than maxsize.
    if (position * 2 + 2 < maxsize && getLeftChild(position) != null){
        // In this code, you always move the parent down, because
        // you never compare the parent with its children.
        if (getRightChild(position) != null){
            if (getLeftChild(position).getPriority() < getRightChild(position).getPriority()){
                tmp = position *2+1;
                swap(position,tmp);
                position = tmp;
                heapDown(position);
            }
            else {
                tmp = position *2+2;
                swap(position,tmp);
                position = tmp;
                heapDown(position);
            }
        }
        else if (getLeftChild(position).getPriority() < getQuesttioner(position).getPriority()){
            tmp = position *2+1;
            swap(position,tmp);
            position = tmp;
            heapDown(position);
        }
    }
}
```

The code you have there is overly complex. You can simplify it like this:

```
// first find the smallest child
leftChildIndex = position * 2 + 1;
if (leftChildIndex >= currentSize) return;
smallestChildIndex = leftChildIndex;
rightChildIndex = position * 2 + 2;
if (rightChildIndex < currentSize) {
    if (getRightChild(position).getPriority() < getLeftChild(position).getPriority()) {
        smallestChildIndex = rightChildIndex;
    }
}
// if the parent is larger than the smallest child,
// then swap and repeat.
if (getQuestioner(smallestChildIndex).getPriority() < getQuestioner(position).getPriority()) {
    swap(position, smallestChildIndex);
    position = smallestChildIndex;
    heapDown(position);
}
```